# Use proxy only if file does not exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, proxy

I try to pass my visitors to an interface via Apache proxy. This works. For customization of the interface (CSS, images etc.) we want that we can overwrite files on the remote server. This is our code:

```
RewriteEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) https://.../$1 [P,L]
```

In the document root of Apache, there is for example an css/style.css. But requesting this in web browser, it shows the version of the site that is fetched via proxy. We tried several things without success.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but might help you.  Maybe you could just proxy two folders to two different locations.  Not sure this works at all, but something to try.


ProxyPass "/site" "http://backend.example.com" connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30
ProxyPass "/site/css_folder_you_want_to_change" "http://css_backend.example.com" connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30

Comment: What does RewriteLog / loglevel rewrite:trace8 say about the -f test?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule by excluding known `css/js/image` extensions:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|ico|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [P,L]
```